# How to find the index of nodes from a grid in python?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, grid

Given an input npy file which contains a 59×45 matrix,having a ONE's grid like structure.The task is it find indices of the nodes of the grid in (y,x) coordinates format.

Seems like a numpy meshgrid concept but don't know how to proceed...

Input files and output pic are given below:

[ https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=1pZGuFy2Cnu-jawZtkwzpRF0bm90mFp74 ][1]

Help me solve this...

Comment: Hi Naina, your task sounds a lot like homework. So I feel like if I posted a solution I would rob you of the learning opportunity of doing it yourself. On the other hand if you post your partial solution and tell me where you're stuck I am willing to help.

Comment: Can you suggest some articles or websites , I can look up to learn and solve this? @user2640045

Comment: Hmm sure check out the python cookbook or watch it on Corey Schafer's youtube channel: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCCezIgC97PvUuR4_gbFUs5g.

You probably should check out how to read files, how to manipulate string and lists and matplotlibs `matshow`.